# Issue with Microsoft EDGE and opening links in new tab. Specifically Google search results. Possibly a RendererCodeIntegrity Issue?

Tags: microsoft-edge, access-violation

Video: https://www.screencast.com/t/nZr2b9KBRSf7

Opening Google Search Results in a new tab results in non functionining pages for me. However if I hit REFRESH on those problematic pages it takes me to the desired site without any issues.

The issue only appears to affect Microsoft EDGE and not Google Chrome. And the broken links seem to only be problematic when opening Google Search results in a new tab.

I reset my browser settings back to default.
I also added the following registry entry as described below for RendererCodeIntegrityEnabled:
https://browserhow.com/how-to-fix-microsoft-edge-status_access_violation/

Finally I changed the shortcut of EDGE to disabled the rendered cod eintegrity as well:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" – disable-features=RendererCodeIntegrity

...

On the problematic pages, the parameters in the URL look like the following:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiYu8Th97

url: 'sa=t'
rct: 'j'
q: [null]
esrc: 's'
source: 'web'
cd: [null]

Comment: According to the video you provided, I did the same operation, but failed to reproduce your issue. The web page can be loaded correctly in Edge( Version 94.0.992.38). In addition to adding commands to the shortcut, you can also try to reinstall Edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolved itself after a Windows Update. Weird bug...